# Polymer-ui-sidebar-menu Content as new

Tags: css, html, polymer

I want to ask how to use *polymer-ui-sidebar(-menu)* with some content.

I want the site to look like this:

```
|------|---------------|
| pol. |               |
| side |               |
|  bar |    Content    |
| menu |               |
|      |               |
|------|---------------|
```

But it looks like this:

```
|------|               ;
| pol. |               ;
| side |               ;
|  bar |  Empty here   ;
| menu |               ;
|      |               ;
|------|  -  -  -  -  -;
|   CONTENT            |
```

(where ; means end of screen)

You can look at the [polymer's example](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer-ui-sidebar-menu/index.html) and add a new element to the end to see it.

Comment: Hi....this components still exists?....your link is not working...

Comment: It's deprecated now. AFAIK the nearest element is IronMenuBehavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<polymer-ui-sidebar>` has `display: flex` on it by default. You can either put `float: left;` on `<polymer-ui-sidear>` or `display: flex` on it's parent container.